# Cross compile simple standard C program on Linux for Mac

Tags: c, linux, macos, clang, cross-compiling

Cross compiling for Mac under Linux is a major PITA. To setup cross compilation you need an Apple developer account, the SDK from XCode etc. I tried it but couldn't get it to work. It seems all the available instructions are outdated anyway.

But the program I want to compile is just a small shell tool that would only need a standard C library (preferable statically linked glibc). No Mac Frameworks or Objective-C needed. It's easy to compile such a binary for Windows, not so much for OS X. It almost seems like all that is missing is the linking part, because you can build mach-o object files like that:

```
clang -target i386-apple-darwin-macho hello_world.c -o hello_world.o -c
```

But of course it's not that simple, because this generates an error:

```
echo $'#ifdef __linux__\n#error "thinks it\'s for linux"\n#endif'| \
    clang -x c - -o /dev/null -c
```

Is there any way to compile a mach-o object for Mac OS X with an unpatched clang under Linux? Is there then a way to link such an object file with a static glibc for Mac so it runs under OS X? And where would I get such an glibc (I guess I have to compile it myself somehow)?

Answer (score 3):

My [OSXCross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) project may be what you are looking for.

> Is there any way to compile a mach-o object for Mac OS X with an unpatched clang under Linux?

Yes. Clang is a cross compiler by default. However, you will also need cctools/ld64 and the Mac OS X SDK.

> Is there then a way to link such an object file with a static glibc for Mac so it runs under OS X?

There is no glibc for Mac OS X, it's simply called `Libc` there. No need to link it statically.

> And where would I get such an glibc (I guess I have to compile it myself somehow)?

You'll need to get the Mac OS X SDK, there is no way around it. Even if you'd manage to build `Libc` by hand then you'd still lack a lot of required libraries.

---

> I know that Mac OS X doesn't ship glibc.

There is no glibc for Mac OS X.

> ... but I write my code against that. E.g. I use PRIuPTR (%zu) etc., does Mac's libc support that?

Yes. AFAIK the `%zu` printf specifier works on everywhere besides Windows.

> That's what I feared. Last time I tried that it was very cumbersome and I couldn't get it to work.

Get a free Apple developer account, then you can download Xcode via https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action.

Once you are done with that follow the SDK packaging instructions.

> What libraries? A libc should only need to make syscalls and not use other libraries.

No.

```
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libc.dylib       
libc.dylib (architecture x86_64):
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 69.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 60061.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 35.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 233.1.2)
        /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 442.1.4)
        /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 353.2.1)
        /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 28.0.0)
        /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 559.20.9)
        /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 862.0.0)
[And so on...]
```

If I can give you one good advice, do not even try to build `Libc` by hand. It's (almost) impossible to do so.
Last time I tried a lot of headers were missing that I couldn't even find via opensource.apple.com.

It's just a waste of time.

And the C library is by far not all you will need for OS X,
a lot of libraries depend on (closed source) Frameworks, libc++, ...

Comment: I know that Mac OS X doesn't ship glibc, but I write my code against that. E.g. I use PRIuPTR (%zu) etc., does Mac's libc support that? "You'll need to get the Mac OS X SDK, there is no way around it." That's what I feared. Last time I tried that it was very cumbersome and I couldn't get it to work. "Even if you'd manage to build Libc by hand then you'd still lack a lot of required libraries." What libraries? A libc should only need to make syscalls and not use other libraries.

Comment: That's unexpected, because under Linux it's:

`$ ldd /lib64/libc.so.6↵            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003cf9600000)↵            linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff14f52000)`

And that's already one more than I would have expected (but yum says ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is part of the glibc package anyway).

Anyway, this all seems too complicated to me just for a tiny shell program. I probably should have written it in Python and used py2exe/py2dmg (or what's it called) for non-Linux.